# How to stop forceformularecalculation apache poi

Tags: java, apache

I am using apache poi 3.12 to generate excel using database data. For some cells I am using formulas also, all calculations are working properly and file was generated successfully. Below is my issue. 
1) Opened the generated file using MS Excel application. 
2) Verified the values and all are Ok. 
3) As the excel file was password protected after verification I tried to close the file.
4) While closing  it was showing message as "MS EXcel recalculates formulas when opening files last saved by an earlier version of excel".

I added "workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(false);" before writing my input stream to workbook.
From API docs it says it will not recalculate the formulas one workbook is opened if set the value to "false".
FYI, I have used unimplemented excel function "YIELD" in one cell.

Can anybody help on this.

Comment: not sure which docs you've read but [these](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#setForceFormulaRecalculation-boolean-) say otherwise

Comment: corrected my typo mistake, I set the value as false.

Comment: from the docs `Whether the application shall perform a full recalculation when the workbook is opened.` sounds like you only tell excel not to recalculate everything, but maybe some formulas or pivot tables recalculate ignoring this flag. there are some problems with formulas in apache poi. Also why should `yield` not be implemented?

Comment: We removed all the unimplemented functions from our code and only kept the implemented functions(like SUM) and set workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(false);
then also when the file was opened and while closing it shows message like "MS Excel recalculates formulas when opening the files last saved by an earlier version of excel" and asking for Save